# How do i automatically make a function start in solidity without putting it in a constructor

Tags: solidity

```
function changeOwnership() public {
        require(lastpresence < block.timestamp -30 seconds);
         _transferOwnership(#ANYADDRESS);

        lastpresence = block.timestamp;
        
    }
```

is it possible to make this function start automatically without me pressing the chaneOwnership function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it using only solidity and your contract. The solidity was designed in a way where there is no nondeterministic behavior inside the contract - thus, automatic function execution is forbidden.

But there is a way to do it if you use not only solidity but also some other solutions.

You can create a service(on the backend, frontend, or even mobile) that periodically calls the needed function via the RPC API of your contract and blockchain RPC endpoint.

Some solidity oracles also provide such a capability - for example, you can do it via [chainlink](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/cron/)